# Tweepy streaming error

Tags: python-3.x, tweepy, python-3.7

I'm trying to analyze the sentiment of the tweets using tweepy and textblob. 
I did pip install tweepy and it was installed successfully, but I get the following error.

Error Message:
File "C:\Users\joshey\Desktop\sent.py", line 2, in 
import tweepy
File "C:\Users\joshey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy__init__.py", line 17, in 
from tweepy.streaming import Stream, StreamListener
File "C:\Users\joshey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tweepy\streaming.py", line 355
def _start(self, async):

```
import tweepy
from textblob import TextBlob

consumer_key= 'CONSUMER_KEY_HERE'
consumer_secret= 'CONSUMER_SECRET_HERE'

access_token='ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE'
access_token_secret='ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET_HERE'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.search('Trump')

for tweet in public_tweets:
print(tweet.text)

analysis = TextBlob(tweet.text)
print(analysis.sentiment)
print("")
```

Is there any problem with the tweepy installation or the code?
Can anyone help me figure out what's the problem? I tried googling, but nothing worked.
Thanks in advance.

Is there any problem with the tweepy installation or the code?
Can anyone help me figure out what's the problem? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange thing is `def _start(self, async)` is nowhere in the codebase, it's `def _start(self, is_async)`. Where is 3.7 getting the former method from?

Comment: Commit 18dad6f that fixed the issue had already been merged into master by the time I was looking at the source. `pip install -U git+https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy.git` works, before they make a formal release with the bugfix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"pip install tweepy" is still not currently functioning with python 3.7, roll back to 3.6.OB1 (and ignore the pip update recommendations).

should work then :)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `async` with `async_` Did the trick for me.

Ref: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1017

Answer (score 0):

Replacing async with async_ worked as stated by user10459541.

Just open the streaming.py file in the Lib\site-packages\tweepy path and replace all occurences with Find&Replace function on Notepad