# How to run a script that uses a faulty library in Heroku?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heroku, bots, tweepy

I am trying to deploy a Python bot on Heroku but I have an issue with Tweepy. I get the same error that is solved here: 
[Tweepy streaming error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48365941/tweepy-streaming-error)

The issue is, I cannot access the library Heroku uses to modify it as the solution suggests, so I'm stuck without being able to correct the library. There are lots of twitter bots running, so there must be a workaround, but I cannot find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue, in addition to the local solution in the question I linked, can also be addressed by defining `python-3.6.6` in the `runtime.txt` instead of the latest version. It is a problem with a redefinition of "async_" in Python 3.7 that still hasn't been solved nor updated.